# Parallel vs series resonant converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, resonant-converter

Why are series resonant converter such as the LLC more used than parallel resonant converters such as the LCC?

Comment: Hi! There's a reason the question editor prompted you whether you were *sure* you wanted to invent two new tags. I removed them; a) there's already tags like [tag:llc-converter] and b) honestly, not quite sure you actually need these tags here, seeing how uncommonly they are. It would make more sense to actually write out the definition of your abbreviations in your question to make it easer to find! I replaced your usage of [tag:resonant] with the more descriptive [tag:resonant-converter].